# error in SED when using arguments and variables in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a script which

1. Takes a string as an argument
2. Use the string to find a TeX file
3. In a for loop - Uses SED to make substitution in and compiles the TeX file
4. Substitution includes changing a header name (and concatenating) which gives the output file a unique name after compilation

The commands are working correctly when I am running them live, however the executing the shell script is giving me the following error

```
./batchscript: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `sed'
./batchscript: line 12: `    sed -i "s|--jobname .*MPa|--jobname ${filename}${i}MPa|g" $CURRENTFILE".tex"'
```

The script is below

```
DIR=`pwd`
filename=$1
CURRENTFILE=$DIR/$filename
for i in {2,5,8,11}     
    sed -i "s|--jobname .*MPa|--jobname ${filename}${i}MPa|g" $CURRENTFILE".tex"
    sed -i "s|pgfplotstableread{.*MPa.dat}|pgfplotstableread{${i}MPa.dat}|g" $CURRENTFILE".tex"                                                         
    arara $CURRENTFILE".tex"
done
```

I tried a couple of syntax variations. I also looked around and read that it this might have to do something the shell responsible for passing variables to sed and it might not work.

Any workarounds using awk or ex can also work for me

Comment: Your `for` statement needs a `do`. As in `for i in {2,5,8,11}; do`.

Comment: Oops!Classic saturday evening syntax errors. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` statement needs a `do`. As in `for i in {2,5,8,11}; do`.